# AppCode: unused statement in .h file

Tags: objective-c, ios, appcode, code-inspection

AppCode is great utility for refactoring and review code. Last time I use Code Inspector in menu: `'Code -> Code Inspect...'`, but this code inspector have some troubles.

General trouble, when code inspector found trouble with `'Unused statement'` with .h file. For example, I have MyClass.h and MyClass.m files. And in MyClass.m AppCode finding Unused statement who is MyClass.h file.

So, how to remove this warning from code inspector? And why I get this warnings? from what?

Thanks.

Comment: This is ObjectiveC and platform Apple iOS.

Comment: Which version of AppCode are you using? I'm using 1.6.2.

Comment: Could you edit your question posting code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added a new class called NewClass, than i run Inspector. As suspected, it told me that class is never used in my project. Indeed, class is in **Unused Code** section of **Inspection Result**.

```
Name:                NewClass.h       
Location:            file NewClass.h       
Problem synopsis:           
Interface 'NewClass' is never used (at line 11)         
Problem resolution:           Safe delete the interface 'NewClass'
```

If you want to mute this control, go to Preferences, Inspection and in **Unused Code** section and uncheck **Unused class** check.
You can see that something is unused since is marked with gray colour.

This answer is based on 1.6.2 and making a naive guess on the cause.